# How to add new flaticons to my website?

Tags: html, css

I have a website template which uses flaticons. It has a folder with files flaticon.css, flaticon.eot, flaticon.ttf, flaticon.svg, flaticon.woff and some others. I can use the icons by simply importing the CSS into a page and doing something like `<i class="flaticon-world-grid">`.

Now I want to download some new flaticons and use them on my site. I found some on flaticon.com and it gives me an option to download it in multiple formats. How to "install" these files and edit my CSS so that I can use the new icons like the ones that are already there?

The css file has content like this:

```
.flaticon-wand2:before {
    content: "\e0fb";
}
.flaticon-wealth:before {
    content: "\e0fc";
}
.flaticon-website34:before {
    content: "\e0fd";
}
.flaticon-world-grid:before {
    content: "\e0fe";
}
```

Which format should I download, where to put the new files, and what to add into the css file to be able to use them?

Comment: download the set that you want and upload them to your public_html folder for your site then use the css code they provide

Comment: It sounds like you would want to set a font face above the CSS you posted and then set the font-family for each of those classes to the new font.  Like the following: [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](http://support.flaticon.com/hc/en-us/articles/205019862-CSS-code-for-Iconfont-) you can use two or more font-face, with different font-family name.

Like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("../fonts/Flaticon.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("../fonts/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="flaticon-"], [class*=" flaticon-"] {
    /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
    font-family: flaticon !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;  
}


.flaticon-arrows:before { content: "\f100"; }
.flaticon-back:before { content: "\f101"; }

/**

 New Fonts to add

 */

@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon1";
  src: url("../fonts/Flaticon1.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Flaticon1.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/Flaticon1.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/Flaticon1.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("../fonts/Flaticon1.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon1";
    src: url(".../fonts/Flaticon1.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  }
}

[class^="flaticon1-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon1-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon1-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon1-"]:after {   
    font-family: Flaticon1;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;   
}
.flaticon1-shapes:before { content: "\f100"; }
.flaticon1-share:before { content: "\f101"; }
```